# Jprofiler and WebSphere 8 Integration Issue

Tags: install4j, websphere-8, jprofiler, perfino

I'm having some issues getting JProfiler connected to a remote WebSphere 8.5.5 instance that is running on Linux. When I start JProfiler on my Windows 10 machine I select the "Profile an application server, locally or remotely" and select the option to integrate with IBM WebSphere 8.x Application Server.

The part I'm having an issue with is the "Specify the remote address" section of setting up the profile. The setup says I need the profiling agent running on target JVM. I download the tar file from the JProfiler website and extract it on Linux machine and run jpenable as it says I should but I get this message.

"No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system. The version of the JVM must be at least 1.6 and at most 11. Please define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to a suitable JVM."

I have made edits to the arguments file that came with the JProfiler in order to remedy this issue but I just can't seem to get JProfiler to see the IBM Java that WebSphere is using on this machine. I have tried using the INSTALL_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE variable in the arguments file by putting the full path to the WebSphere Java install. I have tried using the INSTALL4J_JAVA_PREFIX variable and I have created a INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME variable in the arguments file and put the full path to the WebSphere Java.

Any help would be appreciated greatly appreciated in getting me around this issue. I have verified that WebSphere is using Java version 1.8.0_171.

Answer (score 0):

> but I just can't seem to get JProfiler to see the IBM Java that WebSphere is using on this machine.

That's because IBM JVMs are not supported for attach mode.

> The setup says I need the profiling agent running on target JVM.

Generally, this is achieved by adding an `-agentpath` VM parameter to the profiled VM. The remote address that you are asked for in the wizard will be added as an option to that parameter. The wizard will then modify the server config file and add the complete VM parameter, so you don't have to it manually.

More information is available at

https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/doc/main/profiling.html